# React Chart JS not showing data

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I am using react-chartjs to try and display some data in a line chart. However, it's not showing and I keep running into issues. I can get it to display if I put  in the return, but the data isn't there.

Code:

```
import { Component, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
} from 'chart.js'
import { Chart } from 'react-chartjs-2'

ChartJS.register(
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend
)

import {Line} from 'react-chartjs-2'

const LineData = (props) => {

  console.log(props.data)
  if(props.data) {
    var items = props.data.map((item) => {

    <Line
      datasetIdKey='id'
      data={{
        labels: ['Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug'],
        datasets: [
          {
            id: 1,
            label: '',
            data: [5, 6, 7],
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            label: '',
            data: [3, 2, 1],
          },
        ],
      }}
    />


  })
  
  
  }

      return (
      
        <strong>
          {items}
        </strong>
         
    )

}

export default LineData;
```

Sample props.data:

```
[{
  "url_id": 50,
  "url_name": "https://example.com",
  "created_at": {
    "value": "2022-08-06T01:00:53.750Z"
  },
  "performance_score": "0.46",
}]
```

Comment: We need the example data

Comment: @AdamThomas i added some sample data for you